# How to increase HTTP Timeout in the AndroidDriver class for Appium

Tags: android, jenkins, bitbucket, appium, browserstack

We are attempting to run our tests for our Mobile app on BrowserStack through our Bitbucket pipeline, using Appium version 6.0.0 with the AndroidDriver, which inherits from RemoteWebDriver. We are currently passing the URL to BS with our capabilities (`AndroidDriver(AppiumDriverLocalService service, org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities desiredCapabilities)`), however the test suite always loses connection to the BrowserStack Hub about half way through.

I wanted to try to add a Factory in the Android Driver to increase the HTTP Timeout and see if that would help my case (`AndroidDriver(AppiumDriverLocalService service, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient.Factory httpClientFactory, org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities desiredCapabilities)`). The code as is runs fine when running from my local machine to BS but as soon as we run from Bitbucket or even Jenkins, then the network issues start to occur.

Does anyone have an example on how I would be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeLimitInSeconds);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(“desired xpath”)));
```

Else you can explicitly wait for several seconds using `thread.sleep()`